# How to convert entire dataset of images into sketch with following python code

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

Below is the code by which I convert one image into a sketch. Now my question is that **How I can convert entire dataset of images (88 images of CUHK Dataset) into a sketch and save it in a new directory.**

[image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYADJ.png)